# Accessing crm2011 web service data with visual studio 2008

Tags: web-services, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using visual studio 2008 to create custom reports. But I've always getting the same mistake...

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure.
>   ---------------------------- The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
>   ---------------------------- Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'https://srv-crm/myCompany/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl'.

My site has multiple IIS bindings so I've tried the [following](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/07/04/troubleshooting-microsoft-dynamic-crm-2011-connection-with-outlook/). But still nothing and I got a 404 error instead.

CRM2011 is configured on two separate servers (separate sql server + client side) and I'm tring to access to the service from a test server.

What else could I check?

Any help would be welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having troubles like these accessing the soap web services and using a https protocol, we managed to solve the issue by configuring the RTM CRM 2011 deployment with Claims based authentication and IFD access thanks to [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZD5qaa-G99E).

Hope it will help some of you !